# Passing several fields if meets a criteria to a Hidden Form Field

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, forms

I need to pass multiple filled values to a hidden form field using javascript/jquery. The fields must have a value or don't pass. I can pass the regular text fields with no problem but the checkbox and radio fields always seem to get me. Javascript is not my expertise so I'm willing to learn. Thanks in advance.

**The values we are wanting to capture are:**

1. Questions/comments
2. Product Interests (this can be multiple values)
3. Industry
4. Number of Employees
5. Multiple Locations if "true".

*Each item will be separated by a pipe character.*

```js
$(document).ready(function() {      
        $(function(){ $('#13005,#14604').on("keyup",function(){                  
                commentField = $("#13005").val(); + " || "
                products = $("p.Custom_LR_FormServices input:checkbox:checked").map(function(){return $(this).val()}).get();
                industryField = $("p.RAQFormIndustry input:checkbox:checked").map(function(){return $(this).val()}).get();
                numberEmployees = $;
                multipleLocations = $;                  
                hiddenField =  commentField + " || " + products  + " || " + industryField + "||" + numberEmployees + " || " + multipleLocations;
                $("#14604").val(hiddenField);               
            });
        }); 
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p class="email pd-text required    ">
  <label class="field-label" for="12993">Email</label>
  <input type="text" name="12993" id="12993" value="" class="text" size="30" maxlength="255" onfocus="" />
</p>

<p class="company pd-text required    ">
  <label class="field-label" for="12995">Business Name</label>
  <input type="text" name="12995" id="12995" value="" class="text" size="30" maxlength="255" onchange="" onfocus="" />
</p>

<p class="comments pd-textarea     ">
  <label class="field-label" for="13005">Comments/Questions</label>
  <textarea name="13005" id="13005" onchange="" cols="40" rows="10" class="standard"></textarea>
</p>


<p class="fRAQFormIndustry pd-radio required    ">
  <label class="field-label" for="13039">Industry</label>
  <span class="value"><span class="" style="">
  <input type="radio" name="13039[]" id="147771_47771" value="47771" onchange="" />
  <label class="inline" for="147771_47771">Auto Repair / Dealership</label>
  </span><span class="" style="">
  <input type="radio" name="13039[]" id="147773_47773" value="47773" onchange="" />
  <label class="inline" for="147773_47773">Cleanroom</label>
  </span><span class="" style="">
  <input type="radio" name="13039[]" id="147775_47775" value="47775" onchange="" />
  <label class="inline" for="147775_47775">Food Processing</label>
  </span><span class="" style="">
  <input type="radio" name="13039[]" id="147777_47777" value="47777" onchange="" />
  <label class="inline" for="147777_47777">Healthcare</label>
  </span><span class="" style="">
  <input type="radio" name="13039[]" id="147779_47779" value="47779" onchange="" />
  <label class="inline" for="147779_47779">Manufacturing</label>
  </span><span class="" style="">
  <input type="radio" name="13039[]" id="147781_47781" value="47781" onchange="" />
  <label class="inline" for="147781_47781">Restaurant / Bar</label>
  </span><span class="" style="">
  <input type="radio" name="13039[]" id="147783_47783" value="47783" onchange="" />
  <label class="inline" for="147783_47783">Retail</label>
  </span><span class="" style="">
  <input type="radio" name="13039[]" id="147785_47785" value="47785" onchange="" />
  <label class="inline" for="147785_47785">Other</label>
  </span></span>
</p>
<p class="fCustom_LR_FormServices pd-checkbox required    ">
  <label class="field-label" for="13007">Products</label>
  <span class="value"><span>
  <input type="checkbox" name="13007_47921" id="13007_47921" value="47921" onchange="" />
  <label class="inline" for="13007_47921">Uniforms or Apparel</label>
  </span><span>
  <input type="checkbox" name="13007_47923" id="13007_47923" value="47923" onchange="" />
  <label class="inline" for="13007_47923">Mats, Mops or Towels</label>
  </span><span>
  <input type="checkbox" name="13007_47925" id="13007_47925" value="47925" onchange="" />
  <label class="inline" for="13007_47925">First Aid or Safety Products</label>
  </span><span>
  <input type="checkbox" name="13007_47927" id="13007_47927" value="47927" onchange="" />
  <label class="inline" for="13007_47927">Restroom Supplies or Hand Sanitizer</label>
  </span><span>
  <input type="checkbox" name="13007_47929" id="13007_47929" value="47929" onchange="" />
  <label class="inline" for="13007_47929">Cleaning Chemicals</label>
  </span></span>
</p>
<p class="fCustom_LR_FormEmployees pd-radio required    ">
  <label class="field-label" for="13009">Number of Employees</label>
  <span class="value"><span class="" style="">
  <input type="radio" name="13009[]" id="13009_47765_47765" value="47765" onchange="" />
  <label class="inline" for="13009_47765_47765">1-99</label>
  </span><span class="" style="">
  <input type="radio" name="13009[]" id="13009_47767_47767" value="47767" onchange="" />
  <label class="inline" for="13009_47767_47767">100-249</label>
  </span><span class="" style="">
  <input type="radio" name="13009[]" id="13009_47769_47769" value="47769" onchange="" />
  <label class="inline" for="13009_47769_47769">250+</label>
  </span></span>
</p>
<p class="form-field group-alt2 form-field-col row4 Custom_LR_FormMulitLocation pd-radio     ">
  <label class="field-label" for="13011">We Have Multiple Locations</label>
  <span class="value"><span class="" style="">
  <input type="radio" name="13011[]" id="13011_47787_47787" value="47787" onchange="" />
  <label class="inline" for="13011_47787_47787">Yes</label>
  </span><span class="" style="">
  <input type="radio" name="13011[]" id="13011_47789_47789" value="47789" onchange="" />
  <label class="inline" for="13011_47789_47789">No</label>
  </span></span>
</p>


<p class="form-field  Saved_Items pd-hidden  hidden   ">
  <label>Saved Item Hidden</label>
  <input type="text" name="14604" id="14604" value="" />
  <span id="error_for_14604" style="display:none"></span> </p>
```

**

Comment: Have you tried anything so far?

Comment: @Kinglish - My js code is pretty embarrassing but yes. I'll add it above.

Comment: _The fields must have a value or don't pass_ - does this mean you don't want them in the final result at all if they're empty? If that's the case, how will you know when the result is just a string with pipe delimiters? I would recommend ending up with a json string like `{'products':[1,2,3], 'commentField':'',...}` and so on, so you can at least know what variable goes with what data. Would that kind of result (written into that hidden field) work for you?

Comment: I initially had that thought, too. I think that would be ideal to have the label included.

Comment: @Kinglish the comment field only populates if one of the other fields are 'blur, change, click'. I tried to add keyup but that only makes the comments field work and none others. How do I make sure both work as expected?

Comment: @Kinglish - one last thing I'm unsure of. Can I change the script to display the text string instead of the 'value'?

Comment: Katy - I put a `change` event listener on the form tag instead of individual listeners - any changes to the form will trigger the script. I should have done it that way the first time :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one way. You can just put a `change` event listener on the form tag - any changes to the form will trigger the script. The string that gets written into the hidden field is JSON and it can be easily decoded on the back end.

```js
$('#theForm').on('change', function() {
  let vals = [];
  let prod = [], ind = [];
  $(".fCustom_LR_FormServices input:checked").each(function(){ prod.push(getTextFromElID($(this).attr('id')))})
  vals.push({'commentField': $("#13005").val() || ''})
  vals.push({'products': prod || []})
  vals.push({'industryField': getTextFromElID($(".fRAQFormIndustry input:checked").attr('id')) || ''})
  vals.push({'numberEmployees': getTextFromElID($(".fCustom_LR_FormEmployees input:checked").attr('id')) || ''})
  vals.push({'multipleLocations': getTextFromElID($(".Custom_LR_FormMulitLocation input:checked").attr('id')) || ''})
  $("#14604").val(JSON.stringify(vals));     
})

function getTextFromElID(id) {
return $(`[for=${id}]`).text().trim();
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id='theForm'>
  <p class="email pd-text required    ">
    <label class="field-label" for="12993">Email</label>
    <input type="text" name="12993" id="12993" value="" class="text" size="30" maxlength="255" onfocus="" />
  </p>

  <p class="company pd-text required    ">
    <label class="field-label" for="12995">Business Name</label>
    <input type="text" name="12995" id="12995" value="" class="text" size="30" maxlength="255" onchange="" onfocus="" />
  </p>

  <p class="comments pd-textarea     ">
    <label class="field-label" for="13005">Comments/Questions</label>
    <textarea name="13005" id="13005" cols="40" rows="10" class="standard saver"></textarea>
  </p>


  <p class="fRAQFormIndustry pd-radio required    ">
    <label class="field-label" for="13039">Industry</label>
    <span class="value"><span class="" style="">
  <input type="radio" name="13039[]" id="147771_47771" value="47771"  />
  <label class="inline" for="147771_47771">Auto Repair / Dealership</label>
  </span><span class="" style="">
  <input type="radio" name="13039[]" id="147773_47773" value="47773" />
  <label class="inline" for="147773_47773">Cleanroom</label>
  </span><span class="" style="">
  <input type="radio" name="13039[]" id="147775_47775" value="47775" />
  <label class="inline" for="147775_47775">Food Processing</label>
  </span><span class="" style="">
  <input type="radio" name="13039[]" id="147777_47777" value="47777" />
  <label class="inline" for="147777_47777">Healthcare</label>
  </span><span class="" style="">
  <input type="radio" name="13039[]" id="147779_47779" value="47779" />
  <label class="inline" for="147779_47779">Manufacturing</label>
  </span><span class="" style="">
  <input type="radio" name="13039[]" id="147781_47781" value="47781" />
  <label class="inline" for="147781_47781">Restaurant / Bar</label>
  </span><span class="" style="">
  <input type="radio" name="13039[]" id="147783_47783" value="47783" />
  <label class="inline" for="147783_47783">Retail</label>
  </span><span class="" style="">
  <input type="radio" name="13039[]" id="147785_47785" value="47785" />
  <label class="inline" for="147785_47785">Other</label>
  </span></span>
  </p>
  <p class="fCustom_LR_FormServices pd-checkbox required    ">
    <label class="field-label" for="13007">Products</label>
    <span class="value"><span>
  <input type="checkbox" name="13007_47921" id="13007_47921" value="47921" />
  <label class="inline" for="13007_47921">Uniforms or Apparel</label>
  </span><span>
  <input type="checkbox" name="13007_47923" id="13007_47923" value="47923" />
  <label class="inline" for="13007_47923">Mats, Mops or Towels</label>
  </span><span>
  <input type="checkbox" name="13007_47925" id="13007_47925" value="47925" />
  <label class="inline" for="13007_47925">First Aid or Safety Products</label>
  </span><span>
  <input type="checkbox" name="13007_47927" id="13007_47927" value="47927" />
  <label class="inline" for="13007_47927">Restroom Supplies or Hand Sanitizer</label>
  </span><span>
  <input type="checkbox" name="13007_47929" id="13007_47929" value="47929" />
  <label class="inline" for="13007_47929">Cleaning Chemicals</label>
  </span></span>
  </p>
  <p class="fCustom_LR_FormEmployees pd-radio required    ">
    <label class="field-label" for="13009">Number of Employees</label>
    <span class="value"><span class="" style="">
  <input type="radio" name="13009[]" id="13009_47765_47765" value="47765" />
  <label class="inline" for="13009_47765_47765">1-99</label>
  </span><span class="" style="">
  <input type="radio" name="13009[]" id="13009_47767_47767" value="47767" />
  <label class="inline" for="13009_47767_47767">100-249</label>
  </span><span class="" style="">
  <input type="radio" name="13009[]" id="13009_47769_47769" value="47769" />
  <label class="inline" for="13009_47769_47769">250+</label>
  </span></span>
  </p>
  <p class="form-field group-alt2 form-field-col row4 Custom_LR_FormMulitLocation pd-radio     ">
    <label class="field-label" for="13011">We Have Multiple Locations</label>
    <span class="value"><span class="" style="">
  <input type="radio" name="13011[]" id="13011_47787_47787" value="47787" />
  <label class="inline" for="13011_47787_47787">Yes</label>
  </span><span class="" style="">
  <input type="radio" name="13011[]" id="13011_47789_47789" value="47789" />
  <label class="inline" for="13011_47789_47789">No</label>
  </span></span>
  </p>


  <p class="form-field  Saved_Items pd-hidden  hidden   ">
    <label>Saved Item Hidden</label>
    <input type="text" name="14604" id="14604" value="" style='width:100%;' />
    <span id="error_for_14604" style="display:none"></span> </p>
</form>
```

Comment: One last question, is there a way to pass these as the text and not values? The form is auto populating the values so I have zero control over that.

Comment: Like with this `<input type="radio" name="13039[]" id="147777_47777" value="47777" class='saver' />
  <label class="inline" for="147777_47777">Healthcare</label>` you want to get `Healthcare` and not `47777` ?

Comment: Ok, updated - by using the `id` of the checked inputs, we can search for the corresponding `label` and get the trimmed inner `text()` from it